# Force Horizontal Scroll in MUI X Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

Is there a way to force a horizontal scroll bar to always be present in the MUI X Data Grid? I have a table with dozens of columns and we need to be able to indicate that there are more columns to view. I've tried `overflow-x:scroll` in several different areas (mostly while in DevTools) but nothing seems to change.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: please provide sufficient code to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you really wants to force the scroll bar to be delayed then:

```js
<DataGrid
 ...
 sx={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }}
 ...
/>
```

However, I think that your problem is that you are setting `flex: 1` property in your DataGrid columns.
Can you please try to remove the `flex` property from all your columns?

Comment: Removing `flex: 1` from all my columns fixed the issue and now the table horizontally scrolls. As an aside, I wish the header names didn't get truncated with ellipsis.

Comment: Same as above. For each column I had a flex value and removing them allowed the grid to be scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered something that is pretty neat and may or may not answer your question: MUI DataGrid detects if there is a mouse connected to your computer and shows the horizontal scroll bar. Otherwise if you don't have a mouse and are only using a trackpad the horizontal scroll bar is hidden until you use the trackpad to scroll.

Hope this helps, I was running into the same problem until I plugged in a mouse and voila!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table with dozens of columns and we need to be able to indicate that there are more columns to view

If your dozen columns do not fit in the grid, the overflow-x should be visible. If not it's a bug for which you could open an issue on the repository.

If it's because columns are too small, you can use `minWidth` properties in the column definition

Answer (score 0):

<Box
component="main"
sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3, width: `calc(100vw - ${drawerWidth}px)`  }}

> 

your page content

assign width your root container in vh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).